# Two Questions 1) In a bad condition VS In bad condition 2) I said good bye to him

Tags: articles

1. When I am trying to express that 'I felt really bad yesterday.', should I write 'I was in a bad condition' or 'I was in bad condition'? do I need to put 'a' between 'in' and 'bad'???
2. Is it correct to say (or write) 'I said good bye to him.'?? What I intend to express is not about breaking up or spliting up between lovers. I am intending to say 'I met my friend yesterday and hung out. After that, we went back to each one's home.'

Comment: You *say* [something] to [someone], you #2 it's correct. Although, after a farewell, it's more common (colloquial way) to say *later!* or *see you around!*

Comment: Kwon, it's customary to ask only one question per post on ELL. That makes it easier to answer questions, to mark them with tags. If one asks a couple of questions in one post, they should be at least closely linked and aimed at clarifying some single issue. Please consider splitting your question in two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I was in bad condition**

has a different meaning that you are athletically out of shape and have not been exercising.

Natives will not usually say

> **I was in a bad condition**

to express that they were not feeling well, since it may sound too medical.

They may use a phrase that hints at the reason

> I was **under the weather** *(not feeling well, usually sick)*
>   I **wasn't doing to well** *(not feeling well)*
>   I was **in a bad way** *(really not feeling well, mainly BrE)*
>   I was **hurting** *(code word for hungover)*

The phrases

> **I said goodbye to him.
>
>   We said our goodbyes.
>
>   I said my goodbye to him.**

without additional context, should be used with **caution** as it can mean **finality** either at the end of a relationship or end of one's life. Usually, your particular point (parting) is not spoken explicitly  but implied

> I saw my friend this weekend. We talked for a while and he seemed OK.
>   We'll hopefully see each other again before another 5 years go by.

The listener will naturally assume you both went your separate ways from the context.

> P1: Did you go see Mom this weekend?
>   P2: Yeah, she cried when we said goodbye.

if it is known that Mom is not critically ill, finality is not assumed.

> We said goodbye and he seemed at peace.

screams finality.